# get the mean of colum after concatenating adding one column at the end of another in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, data-science

I have a dataset that looks like this :

```
    Interactor A    Interactor B    Interaction Score   score2
0   P02574  P39205  0.928736    0.375000
1   P02574  Q6NR18  0.297354    0.166667
2   P02574  Q7KML4  0.297354    0.142857
3   P02574  Q9BP34  0.297354    0.166667
4   P02574  Q9BP35  0.297354    0.16666

data.shape = (112049, 5)
```

I want to add `Interactor B` at the end of `Interactor A` column uniquely and add a column that shows their Rank. 
I did this by :

```
cols = [data[col].squeeze() for col in data[['Interactor A','Interactor B']]]
n =pd.concat(cols, ignore_index=True)
n = pd.DataFrame(n,columns = ['AB'])
```

to make the column unique :

```
t = pd.unique(n['AB'])
t= pd.DataFrame(t, columns=[ "AB"])
```

then :

```
t2 = n.groupby(['AB'],sort=False).size()
t2 = pd.DataFrame(t2)
```

finally :
by concatenating t2 and t   :

```
data_1 = pd.concat([t,l], axis=1)


AB  Rank
0   P02574  4


data.shape = (13631, 2)
```

now I want to add the `Interaction Score`   and  `score2` column to DF . if there is duplicate take the mean of their `Interaction Score`  and delete the duplicates and replace the value of the `Interaction Score` by the mean.

I used :

```
score2 = data.groupby(['Interactor A','Interactor B'])['score2'].mean()
score2 = pd.DataFrame(score2, columns=['score2'])
```

the output in this case is like :

```
        score2
Interactor A    Interactor B    
A0A023GPK8  Q9VQW1  0.200000
A0A076NAB7  Q9VYN8  0.000000
A0A0B4JD97  Q400N2  0.000000
Q9VC64  0.090909
Q9VNE4  0.307692

112049 rows × 1 columns
```

but what I is to add columns with  mean of `'score2'` and `'Interaction Score'` column for 13631 unique data that I made. How can achieve this ?? please help.
the final df should be like :

Interactor  Rank    Interaction Score   score2
 P02574      5        0.928736              0.44

ie: score2 is the average of all 'P0257' score that have been in the dataset

Comment: Make you're example shorter, please read how to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I made it smaller, can u help with the answer? @yatu

Comment: It's hard to track how your `data` df is changing throughout this. How are you concatenating `t` and `t2`? Do you reassign that to the `data` object? Please include all relevant code not just snippets.

Comment: It's also unclear on exactly what you're trying to do. Please provide a final DF on what you expect it to look like based on your first `data` df in the first code block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC - You simply need to reshape your data from wide to long and then run aggregation assuming *scores* pair with *interactors* one for one. Consider [`wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) for reshape after setting up stub names and id field. Then, run `groupby().agg()` for counts and means.

**Data**

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd    

txt = '''    "Interactor A"    "Interactor B"    "Interaction Score"   "score2"
0   P02574  P39205  0.928736    0.375000
1   P02574  Q6NR18  0.297354    0.166667
2   P02574  Q7KML4  0.297354    0.142857
3   P02574  Q9BP34  0.297354    0.166667
4   P02574  Q9BP35  0.297354    0.16666'''

data = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), sep="\s+")
```

**Reshape**

```
# FOR id FIELD
data["id"] = data.index

# FOR STUB NAMES
data = data.rename(columns={"Interaction Score": "score A",
                            "score2": "score B"})

df_long = pd.wide_to_long(data, ["Interactor", "score"], i="id", 
                           j="score_type", sep=" ", suffix="(A|B)")

df_long
#               Interactor     score
# id score_type                     
# 0  A              P02574  0.928736
# 1  A              P02574  0.297354
# 2  A              P02574  0.297354
# 3  A              P02574  0.297354
# 4  A              P02574  0.297354
# 0  B              P39205  0.375000
# 1  B              Q6NR18  0.166667
# 2  B              Q7KML4  0.142857
# 3  B              Q9BP34  0.166667
# 4  B              Q9BP35  0.166660
```

**Interactor Aggregation**

```
df_long.groupby(["Interactor"])["score"].agg(["count", "mean"])

#            count      mean
# Interactor
# P02574         5  0.423630
# P39205         1  0.375000
# Q6NR18         1  0.166667
# Q7KML4         1  0.142857
# Q9BP34         1  0.166667
# Q9BP35         1  0.166660
```

**Interactor + Score Groupby Aggregation**

```
df_long.groupby(["Interactor", "score_type"])['score'].agg(["count", "mean"])

#                        count      mean
# Interactor score_type                 
# P02574     A               5  0.423630
# P39205     B               1  0.375000
# Q6NR18     B               1  0.166667
# Q7KML4     B               1  0.142857
# Q9BP34     B               1  0.166667
# Q9BP35     B               1  0.166660
```

**Interactor + Score Pivot Aggregation**

```
df_long.pivot_table(index="Interactor", columns="score_type", values='score',
                    aggfunc = ["count", "mean"])

#            count          mean          
# score_type     A    B        A         B
# Interactor                              
# P02574       5.0  NaN  0.42363       NaN
# P39205       NaN  1.0      NaN  0.375000
# Q6NR18       NaN  1.0      NaN  0.166667
# Q7KML4       NaN  1.0      NaN  0.142857
# Q9BP34       NaN  1.0      NaN  0.166667
# Q9BP35       NaN  1.0      NaN  0.166660
```

Comment: thanks , is it mean of "score A"? how can I add "score B" mean as well?

Comment: Each each *score* is reshaped in parallel with each *interactor*. However, you can run aggregation at each level. See edit.

Comment: Great to hear and glad to help! Happy coding!